# The intermediary model has no field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i'm newbie in Django world
i'm creating a web app to manage products in an online store
i created the models for Catergories and Products
here are my models :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, )
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    nominal_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='prix normal',)
    reduced_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', through='CategoryProducts', through_fields=('category','product'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CategoryProducts(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**`through_fields=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) are ordered such that the first item is a field that refers to the *source model*: the model where you define the `ManyToManyField`, and the second is the *target model*: the model where the `ManyToManyField` is referring to, so you define these as:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Category',
        through='CategoryProducts',
        through_fields=('product', 'category')
    )
```

Comment: i did what you suggested, but when i look in the database, on the 'CategoryProducts' table, i don't find product and category fields

Comment: @WalidOuzzane: you need to define two `ForeignKey`s named `product` and `category` on the `CategoryProducts` model with `ForeignKey`s to `Product` and `Category` respectively.

Comment: The fields are *not* constructed by the `ManyToManyField`, you need to construct these yourself.

Comment: You should then properly migrate the models. Adding a through model where there was already a `ManyToManyField` however will not work. In that case I would advise constructing a new `ManyToManyField` with a custom through model.